# Is it possible to require sass via composer?

Tags: sass, composer-php

I see in composer you can specify `"php": ">=5.3"` as a requirement so I've tried doing

```
`"sass": "*"`
```

and I get a `no matching package found` error when I try to update my dependencies.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Updating the thread, it is is possible. I haven't tried yet, but there is a scss(only) compiler written in PHP.
http://leafo.net/scssphp/ Hope it is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think so. Composer is a PHP package manager written in PHP, while Sass is a Ruby tool. In addition, Ruby has its own package manager: RubyGems.

If you want to manage versions of Sass, I invite you to use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) and [Gemfile](http://bundler.io/v1.6/gemfile.html).